# On a shared drive, how prevent users from changing folder structure, while allowing them to change a content of these folders?

Tags: windows, network-shares, group-policy, shared-folders

### I have a shared network drive which is shared by means of GPO.

This drive has some folder structure with many nested subfolders each of which could contain files. 
I want:

1. I want to prevent users of shared drive from changing a folder structure.
2. I want users of shared drive to be able to change/alter a content of the folder structure. I.e. to copy/move/replace/delete files, create new files, open/save files, change files.

I'd preffer a solution which does this by GPO on domain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by special permissions. Create a new GPO and navigate to:

```
Computer Config > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System
```

right-click the *"File System"* node and choose *"Add File"*

choose your root folder, then in the permission window click on *"advanced"* then on *"add"*.

In this window choose your principal like `domain\users`, type: *"allow"* , apply to: *"files only"*

choose the permissions which you want to give your users, on your selected root folder, for files only.

here's also a blog post about it: https://msdirectoryservices.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/set-ntfs-folder-permissions-using-gpo/

**Edit:** I had another thought about it. I wouldn't do this via GPO, since it's on a network drive. Just set those permissions on your root folder without GPO. GPO would always renew the permissions which could be bad. this just has to be set once, not everytime some computers start. You should only do stuff like this via GPO, if the folder you want to protect is on a local drive and targets more than one machine. e.g if all 200 computers of your xy department need *"files only"* modify permission on a root folder in their C:\

if you're doing this for your network drive without GPO, it's the same procedure like i explained above, but locally, not inside a GPO. start at "choose your root folder..."